# What should I use instead of templated enums?

Tags: c++, templates, enums, idioms

In my code, I use something like the following:

```
enum {
    foo = sizeof(some_type_t) < 32 ? 1 : 2,
    bar = some_constexpr_function() - N,
    baz = foo + bar,
    // etc.
}
```

for a bunch of compile-time constants for which I want to ensure there will be no run-time storage; and I have a few functions which use these constants.
N is some constant we get from elsewhere.

Now I want to take my code and templatize it: N is no longer a global constant but a numeric template parameter. Now, If I was doing this:

```
template <size_t N> f()
{
    enum {
        foo = sizeof(some_type_t) < 32 ? 1 : 2,
        bar = some_constexpr_function() - N,
        baz = foo + bar,
        // etc.
    }
}
```

That would work; but - it's limiting me to using these constants in a single function; I want to have several. In C++, we can't have

```
    template <size_t N>
    enum {
        foo = sizeof(some_type_t) < 32 ? 1 : 2,
        bar = some_constexpr_function() - N,
        baz = foo + bar,
        // etc.
    }
```

What would be an elegant, or perhaps the idiomatic, way of achieving the equivalent of this templatization?

Comment: How do you even expect this to work with anonymous enum

Comment: I've done some [similar stuff](https://gist.github.com/makulik/7963331) once.

Comment: I don't really get what is the point of enumerator here. Just define normal constants. The phrase "I don't want there to be any run-time storage for" is somewhat strange because if you are going to use them for some runtime computations most likely they will be copied by value.

Comment: @Sopel: I don't. That's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 4):

Just like you were told in the comments, I don't see a point insisting on having those named constants under one enum. Just have a bunch of `constexpr` variables in a single namespace scope. You can get the same net effect:

```
namespace constants {
    namespace detail {
                using underlying_t = int;
    }
    template<size_t N>
    constexpr detail::underlying_t foo = sizeof(some_type_t) < 32 ? 1 : 2;

    template<size_t N>
    constexpr detail::underlying_t bar = some_constexpr_function() - N;

    template<size_t N>
    constexpr detail::underlying_t baz = foo<N> + bar<N>;
}
```

They are all `constexpr`, so they are easily run time constants, and you can control the underlying type in a single place if you need to. Also, you can either access them by a fully qualified id, or bring them all in with a using directive.

Comment: These are likely to have run-time storage. I want to avoid that.

Comment: @einpoklum - You are misinformed.

Comment: Can you enlighten me with a link?

Comment: @einpoklum - Sure, here's [gcc at -O0](https://godbolt.org/g/qroRo8). You'll note there is no storage for the variable. `esi` is loaded directly with `1`.

Comment: That example breaks by changing [a single character](https://godbolt.org/g/4BDLGs). Now, you could argue "well, you shouldn't use a reference" - and you're probably right, but that doesn't even get me a warning. I want a _guarantee_ that there will be no storage. Now - don't get me wrong, I have nothing against your approach, it's just not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @einpoklum You can't have a pointer to a compile time constant.

Comment: @einpoklum - You are kinda shifting the goal post here. You start with saying the storage *likely* to be allocated. It's not. Then you proceed to prove it with an *unlikely* use case. You want to protect yourself from Murphy? I can respect that. But you prove your point with a Machiavellian (albeit fairly simple) device.

Comment: I'll concede that the word 'likely' was misplaced. It's likely if you're writing a library and can't control the silly (or not so silly) ways people will be using your code.

Comment: @einpoklum and that's why you don't

Answer (score 1):

What I'm doing so far is putting my enum in a dummy holder class, which *can* be templated:

```
template <size_t N>
struct params
{
    enum {
        foo = sizeof(some_type_t) < 32 ? 1 : 2,
        bar = some_constexpr_function() - N,
        baz = foo + bar,
    };
}
```

But then I have to write `params::foo`, `params::bar` everywhere, which is tedious:

```
do_stuff_with(params::foo, params::bar)
```

instead of

```
do_stuff_with(foo, bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe overloading comma constexprly would suit your needs?

```
#include <utility>

enum params {
    foo = 1,
    bar = 2,
    baz = 3
};


struct some_type_t { };
constexpr std::size_t some_constexpr_function() {
    return 0;
}


constexpr std::size_t operator ,(params P, std::size_t N) {
    switch (P) {
        case foo:
            return sizeof(some_type_t) < 32 ? 1 : 2;
        case bar:
            return some_constexpr_function() - N;
        case baz:
            return (foo, N) - (bar, N);
    }
    return 0;
}


template <std::size_t>
struct example { };

int main() {
    example<(baz, 2)>{};
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iPtub0EbRdNr07eA)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I find the presence of many open-brackets-close-brackets somewhat confusing though.

Comment: @einpoklum how about [overloading comma](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iPtub0EbRdNr07eA)? :)

Comment: Kudos for originality, but - this means no chance of automatic template parameter resolution in functions already templated on N. And that's if we ignore the hell for people who want to understand what's going on...

Comment: @einpoklum automatic template parameter resolution? you mean like since c++17's deduction guides or some other construct? Either way - I don't think your dummy wrapper have this ability neither or am I missing something...(?) As for understandability - people decide what becomes idiom and you don't argue with idioms :)